# Animate multiple background image in one div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, jquery-animate

I need a smart/tough guy to help me with my issue right now.. please check [div that set css multiple background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmbK5.png) ... in that image I set the background of a div in a gradient color while I called other background images that looks polygonal, and the css is something like this:

```
.at{
  height: 650px;
  padding-top: 130px;
  background-image: url(../../../img/2nd_element.png),
                    url(../../../img/1st_element.png),
                    url(../../../img/3rd_element.png),
                    url(../../../img/4th_element.png),
                    linear-gradient(to bottom, #017a92 0%,#91d2c1 100%);
  background-position: 3em 60px, left bottom, 70% -90px, right top, left bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat;
}
```

I needed to animate these different background images with offset(and it depends on the scrolling page that if this content is centered).
for example: bg-image1 = will appear after 3s, bg-image2 = will appear after 4s, bg-image3 = will appear after 5s.. then etc etc... until the polygonal background images completed.

I'm not sure if this can be done by jQuery or javascript or css3 animation or svg animation but I think you get my point sir!  thanks for helping! looking forward to donate who can help me with this! thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far and what research have you done?

Comment: @Mang Inasar Whatever you are looking for is known as "carousel".

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this. But you can split it to 5 `div`s and set the right animation for each of them.

Comment: Also, you can see [this](https://davidwalsh.name/multiple-background-css-animations) tutorial.

Comment: If I understand, you have 5 different background and you need to animate each to "build" one background with all the other 5? The first solution I think is to create 5 div as @MoshFeu suggest then re-create your unique background with them. For the animation, you can use "keyframe" or some CSS with "translate" properties for example and you can trigger it with some jQuery (scroll, click, load, etc.)